# Für Luft gibt es "entlüften"; für Gas, "entgasen". Was entspricht folgenden Gasen: Stick-, Wasser- und Sauerstoff?

Tags: verb

Für Luft existiert das Verb *entlüften*. Dem Nomen *Gas* entspricht *entgasen*.

Welche Verben entsprechen den folgenden Gasen?

> 1. Stickstoff
> 2. Sauerstoff
> 3. Wasserstoff.

Mein Versuch für Nummer **2**, nämlich *entsäuern* ist nicht richtig und *entsauerstoffen* klingt abgefahren schlecht. Soll ich mit den lateinischen Nomen versuchen? Etwa *entnitro-etwas* für Nummer **1**?

(Auch) ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob diese Wörter existieren. Wenn nicht, wäre es dann interessant zu erfahren, warum es im Englischen (deoxygenation) und in anderen Sprachen (etwa Spanisch: *desoxigenación*) so leicht solche Verben sich ableiten lassen und im Deutschen nicht.

Comment: Ich bin mir gar nicht sicher, ob es dafür entsprechende Wörter gibt...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Bzgl. deines Kommentars habe ich ein Edit gemacht. Also bestimmt findet man diese Wörter im Wörterbuch nicht (auch nicht die englische bwz. spanische Begriffe. Aber *existieren* gleicht nicht *im Wörterbuch sein*).

Comment: Schon *entgasen* klingt für mich künstlich, nach technischer Sprache.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ist es auch so :) Zum Beispiel [hier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deoxygenation). Wie sagt man das?

Comment: mir fällt gerade auf, dass im Englischen, bzw. Spanischen das Präfix *"de(s)-"* genutzt wird.  --> *"denitrierung"*??

Comment: @c.p. in diesem Zusammenhang ist das vielleicht eher eine [Reduktion](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduktion_(Chemie)#Abgabe_von_Sauerstoff)

Comment: @Vogel612 der Link zur Reduktion schlägt auch eine Variante vor: einfach *Sauerstoffsabgabe*, Stickstoffsabgabe und *Wasserstoffsabgabe*? Wie klingt das einem Muttersprachler? Künstlich noch?

Comment: @c.p. Ich würde es ohne das 's' in der Mitte machen, aber ansonsten ganz gut. Das Problem daran ist, dass Abgabe freiwillig klingt --> Das Gas wird einfach so abgegeben und muss nicht extrahiert werden.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Die ganze Sprache ist künstlich. Nur hören kann man es natürlich nicht. Wenn Du nie mit Entgasungen zu tun hast ist Dir das Wort fremd - wenn doch dann nicht. Das hat aber nichts mit dem Wort zu tun, sondern ist mit jedem Wort so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nimm die Vorsilbe *de* und die Fremdwörter für die Gase, de...(?), **deoxygenisieren**, **dehydrogenisieren**, oder kombinieren zu *Sauerstoff entgasen*,...

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt sicher keine allgemein bekannten oder allgemein verwendeten Verben. Im Falle eines Tanks könnte man `Gas ablassen` oder `Sauerstoff ablassen` verwenden, dies gilt aber speziell für Behälter, in denen ein Gas i. Allg. unter Druck aufbewahrt wird.

Auf manchen Mineralwasserflaschen findet man den Satz "Enteisent und mit Kohlensäure versetzt". Enteisent, als Partizip von ent-eisen-en, ist schon etwas abenteuerlich und wird eher nicht verstanden; aber die Tatsache, dass selbst in diesem Satz "mit Kohlensäure versetzt" und nicht "Carbonifiziert" oder Ähnliches steht, bedeutet eigentlich mit ziemlicher Sicherheit, dass es auch im technischen oder chemischen Fachjargon kein entsprechendes Verb gibt. Somit würde ich annehmen, dass auch für das "Gegenteil" kein Fachverb existiert.

Die Google-Suche nach "enthydrogenisieren" sowie "entoxigenisieren", was ich mir jeweils als Ehestes vorstellen könnte, findet für beide Worte 0 Treffer.

Man müsste also im Deutschen den Vorgang umschreiben, beispielsweise mit "Vor der Abfüllung wird dem Gasgemisch der Sauerstoff entzogen" oder "Sauerstoff, Stickstoff und Wasserstoff werden abgetrennt und jeweils einzeln in Gasflaschen verpackt".

Das sind bisher immer die Fälle, wo mit Gemischen hantiert wird, wo also keine chemische Reaktion stattfindet. Für den Fall von chemischen Reaktionen sind Worte wie `Oxidation`, `Reduktion`, `Nitrierung` etc. geläufig. Aus der Eingangsfrage denke ich aber, dass dies eher nicht gemeint ist.

Answer (score 4):

"Entgasen" und "entlüften" sind problematische Wörter im professionellem Umfeld.
Wird. z.B. ein Raum komplett oder teilweise "entgast", würde ich "evakuieren" empfehlen.

Im professionellem Arbeitsumfeld wird "evakuieren" immer dann benutzt, wenn der Raum einen niedrigeren Druck als der Atmosphärendruck hat, "Gas ablassen" immer dann wenn das Gas von selbst aus dem Behälter strömt. "Entgasen" meint eigentlich immer das Gas aus einem Stoffgemisch komplett zu entfernen.

Wenn man aus einem Gasgemisch eines der Gase entfernen möchte (z.B. durch einen Filter oder eine Gaszentrifuge), wird genau dies beschrieben: "Sauerstoff entziehen"; "Sauerstoff herausfiltern".

Wird Luft aus einem Behälter herausgepumpt, wird ebenfalls "evakuiert", strömt die Luft von selbst heraus, spricht man entweder von "entlüften" wenn die Luft dann komplett raus ist (z.B. Heizungsrohre), oder von "Luft ablassen", wenn nur etwas von der Luft abgelassen wird (z.B. bei einem Autoreifen).

Answer (score 2):

Auch wenn Luft ein Gasgemisch ist, versteht man umgangssprachlich unter Gas eher giftige Gase. Daher kommt es auf den Zusammenhang an.

Für das Entfernen eines Gases gibt es nicht für jedes Gas ein eigenes Verb. Die Darstellung von theambee ist korrekt, aber es ist umgangssprachlich auch möglich, von Entgasen zu sprechen, wenn eben nicht Luft gemeint ist. Gerade Sauerstoff würde da nicht passen, auch wenn ein Großteil der Luft aus Stickstoff besteht.

Für die richtige Wahl des Verbs kommt es meiner Meinung nach auf Zusammenhang und Verfahren an. Wenn z. B. eine Öffnung geöffnet wird, eignet sich entlüften. Wenn das Gas durch Vakuum entfernt wird, würde man eher von vakuumisieren sprechen. Der Stoff würde dann im Zusammenhang erwähnt, also z. B. Stickstoff durch Vakuum entfernen.

Answer (score 1):

Entlüften und entgasen haben nichts mit dem tatsächlichen Stoff zu tun (auch Luft ist schließlich ein Gas). Ich würde folgende Regel verwenden:

- Entgasen: Ein Gas wird einem Feststoff oder einer Flüssigkeit entzogen.
- Entlüften: Ein Gas wird aus einem Raum geleitet (z.B. aus Heizungsrohren).

Comment: Luft ist genauer gesagt ein Gasgemisch. Aber das nur am Rande :-)